# How can I calculate out the 'specific charge' of an atom?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, atoms, charge, subatomic

I know that it's charge/mass. But what steps do I take to calculate the specific charge of say, carbon-12? What about ions too?

Comment: This would be better suited for Chem.SE

Comment: @BrandonEnright Not really, but I would close it anyway because it is essentially asking for a walkthrough, which we don't do here.

Answer (score 1):

Specific charge is indeed the ratio of charge and mass, but since an atom is made up of neutrals and charged particles, you need to account for them. Thus, you'd use

$$
\eta=\frac{q\left(n_p-n_e\right)}{n_pm_p + n_nm_n + n_em_e}
$$

where $\eta$ is the specific charge (my own variable, don't believe it's standard), $m_i$ is the mass of $i$ (neutrons, protons, electrons), $n_i$ is the number of those in the atom, $q$ is the charge. For an atom, this is going to be zero because $n_p=n_e$.

Comment: Note, though, that the nuclear mass need not equal the added masses of its constituent nucleons.